# Graph Theory, West, 2nd ed, Exercise 1.2.14

Tags: graph-theory

The claim to prove, or disprove is as follows:

> The union of the edge sets of distinct $u,v$-paths must contain a cycle.

The proposed solution is the following:

> **Proof (extremality)**: Let $P$ and $Q$ be distinct $u$,$v$-paths. Since a path in a simple graph is determined by its set of edges, we may assume (by symmetry) that $P$ has an edge $e$ not belonging to $Q$. Within the portion of $P$ before $P$ traverses $e$, let $y$ be the last vertex that belongs to $Q$. Within the portion of $P$ after $P$ traverses $e$, let $z$ be the first vertex that belongs to $Q$. The vertices $y$, $z$ exist, because $u,v \in V(Q)$. The $y$,$z$-subpath of $P$ combines with the $y$,$z$- or $z$,$y$-subpath of $Q$ to form a cycle, since this subpath of $Q$ contains no vertex of $P$ between $y$ and $z$.

My question is that if this is wrong, because I can think in the example where the two paths are $P_n$ and $P_m$ ($n\neq m$) and both coincide in just one vertex. Such example has no cycle, and the graph is the union of $P_n$ and $P_m$. Is it a valid counterexample to the proof?

Comment: If $P_n$ and $P_m$ are both $u,v$ paths, then they should at least have $u$ and $v$ in common.  So it can't be that they coincide in just one vertex.

Comment: You're right, I think that what bothered me is to say two different walks starting at $u$ and $v$. I mean, different in what sense? if they both start and end at the same pair of vertices, they do not look too different from a pair of paths that start at different couples of vertices.

Comment: They're different in the sense that they don't both contain exactly the same edges.